# how to display two surfaces over each other?

Tags: android, surfaceview, augmented-reality

I have a 3D cube and I open the camera preview, and I want to see this rotating cube displayed over the camera.

What I attempted is, inside the SurfaceChanged method of the class that implements `surfaceHolder.callback`, I call `camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback(){ }`
as follows:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
.......
.......
.......
camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            glSurface.setRenderer( new MyRender());
            setContentView(glSurface);
        }
    });
```

This code results in, displaying the camera preview for a few seconds until the surface is changed, then, the camera preview disappears and the 3D cube appears on a black background.

Is there anyway to show both surfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I recall, you have to set the CameraPreview ontop of the GlView. Thats not intuitive, but should work.
here is a link that may help you: http://digitalbreed.com/2009/android-render-opengl-on-top-of-camera-preview

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own offscreen compositing, then draw the result into a single SurfaceView. See [this sample code](https://github.com/ldo/3D-Compass) for details.